# Class name in java should be camelcase - mandatory or not?

Tags: java

According to oracle docs: the class name in java should  be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

Is this just a good practice rule or a mandatory rule?

(I'm a beginner so please excuse me if this is too silly)

Comment: BTW: it would have literally taken you 3 seconds to just try it out.

Comment: I tried it out n both were working fine.. I was just confused because of that.

Comment: FWIW, class names in Java are `BumpyCase` by convention, not `camelCase`, which is used for variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a good practice, but about every one follows it. Better readability and, at least Eclipse, you can use all capital letters for intellisense (suggestions).

So if you have these variables :

- myVariable
- myFirstVariable
- mySecondVariable

You can be suggested the last one by typing "mSV". Same is applied for classes or interfaces.

Comment: right so not mandatory, class name is still valid if it is myFirstProgram.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't, because you can easily distinguish variables and classes/interfaces.

Comment: Just in case you don't know, if you are satisfied with the answer, you shall accept it. Pleasure.

Comment: this was a general question so I was not sure about that. :p

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered correctly, but here's *why* that answer is correct.  You might find this helpful in the future.

One thing you'll notice about programmers is that they tend to be very precise in their choice of words.  If the documentation says "should", then it means (or should mean) exactly that.  If something is mandatory, good documentation will describe it using words like "must" or "shall".

Comment: I'd say *specifications* are very precise in their terms. Programmers vary.

Comment: Indeed. I cannot even begin to count the instances where someone uses the term "function" to refer to a "method" in Java, for example. Or confuses "parameter" with "argument".

Comment: @JörgWMittag (Actual) parameter vs (Formal) parameter in some dialects. Depending on how pedantic you wish to be about the definition of function, Java either has no functions or every method is a function, there is no useful distinction to be drawn in either case

Comment: @JörgWMittag, let's not forget that in "pure OO" terms, all methods are procedures (perform actions, but do not return data), so calling them "functions" is doubly wrong! ;) (however, at the end of the day, they are all sub routines really) :)